# ¿Tengo que poner un atributo en constructor de una clase si es que al crear una instancia de la clase ese atributo puede estar o no?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase con 8 atributos, sin embargo, al instanciarla necesito poder obviar uno de los 8. ¿Ese atributo que obviaré lo tengo que poner en el constructor?
Acá el código de la clase (el atributo codigoAlmacen es el que puede o no ser utilizado en las instancias):

```
public class Orden {
    
    int codigoOrden;
    String fechaOrden;
    String tipoOrden;
    String incotermOrden;
    int codigoCotizacion;
    String codigoTransporte;
    int codigoAlmacen;
    int codigoCarga;
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Podrías usar herencias. Por ejemplo, tener `class Orden` sin `codigoAlmacen` y `class OrdenConCodigoAlmacen extends Orden` para las que sí lo tengan. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El constructor es una función más de la clase. Puede tener todos los parámetros que tú quieras, así como ninguno. En lo que se diferencia de una función normal es que tiene el mismo nombre de la clase, no se indica tipo de retorno ni se retorna nada.

Lo único a tener en cuenta es que sin constructores la clase no puede instanciarse. Por lo que si no escribiste ninguno, el compilador le asignará uno por defecto sin parámetros y así puedes instanciarla.